# Jar compatibility from java6 to java8

Tags: java, jar, java-8, migration, compatibility

Im upgrading my web application from java 6 to java 8. I'm using a list of jars in my web application. Is there any tool/mechanism available to check whether the lib **jars** compatible with java 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Java 8's JVM can run Java 6 code just fine. It's the *other* direction that's an issue, but running older code on newer JVMs isn't a problem.

Obviously, you'll want to test thoroughly before doing this in production.

Comment: it *could* have minor hiccups (we had such issues with generics with some bug fixes in 8 that were not present in 7)...

Comment: @Eugene: Ouch. Obviously, important to test. :-) But if code was (inadvertently) relying on buggy behavior...

Comment: Java7 introduced new methods on JDBC interfaces. That change broke backwards compatibility of existing Java6 JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) and [Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html).

Be aware that one of the incompatibilies is that JDBC changed in Java7 and these changes are not backwards compatible.  So if you use JDBC in your application then you need upgrade to Java7+ compatible JDBC driver(s).